# Is it possible to watch for, or somehow detect, when a child dom node gets appended to some parent?

Tags: javascript, dom

Lets say I have a child node `a`, can I detect when `someArbitraryParent.appendChild(a)` happens if I don't know what the parent will be?

Comment: Do you have control over the code that does this addition of node?

Comment: @B T if you use jquery , you probably want to look into `on()` and the `change` event .

Comment: @RahulNanwani I do actually have that control, but I'm building a library, and I was hoping I wouldn't have to require that attachments be made via a special function. Because say, if someone does a raw `node.appendChild(something)` the library then wouldn't work. I was hoping I could feasibly detect when a node is added to the document to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by myf, your best bet is to use the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API to observe the `body` element. What's not so easy to guess is the need to set the `subtree` option to `true` when configuring the observer, in order to listen to DOM changes for all descendants of `body`.

```js
// Select the link node
var link = document.querySelector('#link');
// This variable will hold the parent element when the link is appended to it
var detectedParent;

// Insert function triggered by the button for test purposes
var container = document.querySelector('#container2');
function insert() {
    container.appendChild(link);
}    
 
// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  // Traverse every mutation
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++)
        // Test if the link element has been added to mutation.target
        if (mutation.addedNodes[i] == link) {
            // Store the parent and proudly alert its ID
            detectedParent = mutation.target; 
            alert('ID of link container is : ' + detectedParent.id);
            // Turn off potentially costly DOM listening
            observer.disconnect(); 
        }   
  });    
});
 
// Configure the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, 
      // This option allows you to listen to all descendants of body
      subtree: true
};

window.onload = function() {
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('body'), config);
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container1"></div>
<div class="container" id="container2"></div>
<div class="container" id="container3"></div>
<div><button onclick="insert()">Insert the link</button></div>
<div class="park"><a id="link">Link</a></div>
```

Comment: Sounds like this is the only way to do it. It would be nice tho, if there was a way without listening to every `appendChild` that happens on the page.

Comment: Well, if you are able to narrow the spectrum of possible parents for your element, you can move the observer down the DOM tree or set up multiple observers targeting specific classes and/or ids, considerably reducing the workload.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, I can't

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on `body`.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit more and provide an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

DOMNodeInserted or DOMSubtreeModified  is probably what you're looking for.
For a complete list of mutation events that are available (albeit ie9+) you can look at the mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Depending on what your ultimate goal is you can try something like this, in this example I'm assuming a has a unique class that allows it to be detected.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
   if (event.target.classList.contains("custom-class")) {
     // perform operations
   }
});
```

Comment: This might not be a long-lasting solution. DOM Events are a deprecated API, see your own link.

Comment: true, but mutation observers currently only work on most edge implementations http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver. A better solution would use mutation observers and fallback to mutation events for the best compat. Still I don't know if this is possible in < ie9.